# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't come back from hibernation, but restarts

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 20.04, hibernate

When `sudo systemctl hibernate` is used, it seems to shut down the system, and when it is started again, the previous state is not there (e.g. no previously opened windows, it's like a fresh start).

I also tried `sudo apt install hibernate` and `sudo hibernate`, but it just seems to lock the screen at most without any hibernation.

My `/etc/default/grub` file has this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=<SWAP_ID>"
```

And here is how my boot SSD drive (GPT system) is configured (output from `sudo fdisk -l`):

```
Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1      2048    391167    389120   190M EFI System
/dev/sdc2    391168  68751359  68360192  32.6G Linux swap
/dev/sdc3  68751360 478908415 410157056 195.6G Linux filesystem
```

Secure boot is disabled from the BIOS.

In case it's relevant, I have 2 other drives /dev/sda (SSD) and /dev/sdb (HDD), but they are not used for any OS installation.

How do I get hibernate to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in `/etc/default/grub` is wrong.

It should be `resume=UUID=<swap UUID>` or `resume=/dev/sdc2`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work "as is" in my case.

The steps that worked for me were:

1. As the accepted answer states, modify the `/etc/default/grub` file to have this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<SWAP_UUID>"`. (The swap UUID can be got from running `cat /etc/fstab | grep swap`)
2. Run `sudo update-grub`
3. Reboot PC. Now hibernation should work.

The accepted answer is missing step 2.

[Complete guide here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/)